# Win10 Anniv Update broke time display in traybar

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607

Since I updated to Win 10 Pro Anniversary Update (version 1703) the separator between hours and minutes in the display of the time in the traybar is broker (a **square** is displayed):

[image]

How can it be displayed correctly ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What language packs other then the default language pack do you have installed?

Comment: Anniversary Update is 1607? Do you mean creators update?

Comment: This happened after update to 1703. About the language, this is a french Windows 10, without additional language.